# What is the simplest way to display status HTML on a Facebook product page

Tags: facebook

I want to display some static html when clicking one of the buttons at the top of a Facebook product page.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this ? Do I really need an SSL certificate to do this ?

I have a web server where I can get the html but if this requires an SSL I might be tempted to just add static html in stead of leading a page from this web site.

Any beginners guide would be helpful.

Comment: if you want to serve it from your server you need an certificate, if its only some text/html you want to display, you can use one of the many "static html" apps out there. https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+static+html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the application on your own server,
inside Facebook (Canvas/Timeline Tab) you will need a signed SSL,
but SSL is not required if you run the app on your domain.

Additionally you can make use of the free Heroku account offered by Facebook.
This way you don't need to own a server or an ssl certificate and your app runs on cloud.

You can find the Heroku option in the Developer App/Basic Info/Hosting URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558/